# How do I rename a window via a prompt command in iTerm2?

Tags: bash, iterm2

I want to open a terminal session in iTerm2 and send text to rename the window title to "Jupyter Notebook", and then open a Jupyter notebook:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;Jupyter Notebook\007"';  VAR="jupyter notebook"; $VAR
```

However, the above commands will first open a Jupyter Notebook, and *then* rename the terminal title to "Jupyter Notebook" *after* I interrupt the notebook session using CMD-C.

How do I rename the window title before the notebook session opens?

Comment: The prompt command is executed just before it displays the next prompt. The prompt isn't displayed until the command finishes.

Comment: Prompt command is usually used to make the title reflect something that changed during the previous command, such as changing directory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this with `PROMPT_COMMAND`. It's intended only for updating the prompt or window title to pick up changes that were made during the previous command, such as `cd`. It's not executed until the command completes and the shell is about to print the next prompt -- that's why `PROMPT` is in the name.

Use an alias or function to update the title and run the command:

```
alias jnb='echo -ne "\033]0;Jupyter Notebook\007"; jupiter notebook'
```

Comment: The same issue arises when aliasing.

Comment: I had incorrect syntax in the alias definition. When I fixed that, it works for me. I don't have Jupytor, I changed that to `vi`, but it changed the window title while `vi` was running.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating another environment variable:

```
TITLE='echo -ne "\033]0;Jupyter Notebook\007"'; $TITLE; VAR="jupyter notebook"; $VAR
```

But I still don't understand bash's behavior. If I attempt to set a title before running, say, an Apache Spark shell, then bash ignores the echo command and duly fires up a Spark shell:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;Apache Spark\007"; spark-shell
Last login: Tue Jan 22 11:54:15 on ttys001
MacBook:directory user$ 'echo -ne "\033]0;Apache Spark\007"'; spark-shell
2019-01-22 12:25:25 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
```

Apparently, commands that come after the echo command can override the echo. If someone could explain this behavior, I'd really appreciate it.